# Magento2 custom css not included in head after upgrading the website

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, css

I upgraded a website from 2.0.5 to 2.1.5. The website uses a custom theme.

In this theme, I added some css to include in the layout

> app\design\frontend\Vendor\themename\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml

But none of the CCC are being included in the head tag in frontend. The upgraded website uses the correct theme, because it loads the content of phtml for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the syntax are correct

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <css src="css/custom.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Also, make sure that CSS is on your following path

```
app/design/frontend/package/theme/web/css/custom.css
```

And run the following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

If still not working, Clear your browser cache or try different browsers.

Comment: It is solved. I don't know exactly what is the point that I have missed, but I did not re-run the upgrade command when it was not working, but only deployment and flush cache. So I re-ran one by one the command lines you mentionned. I made a change in theme table too: all my theme type was set to virtual (1 value) and I changed it to physical (0 value). And I used a theme that have a parent, so I put in the child theme some parents files.

Comment: @Mirindra : Glad you resolved it